# DC search using a filter in just one action

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakedc

I have an `devices/index` page where by default I don't want to show "out of order" devices unless I flag a proper checkbox

so I used the CakeDC search plugin 3 and I dit

DevicesTable

```
 public $filterArgs = [


     'include_out_of_order' => [
        'type' => 'finder', 
        'finder' => 'outOfOrder',
        'allowEmpty' => true
    ],  

     // ...
     // lot of other filters
     // ...

 ]


public function findOutOfOrder($query, array $options)
{
    if(isset($options['include_out_of_order']) &&  $options['include_out_of_order'] == true)
        return $query;   
    else
        return $query->where(['Devices.device_status_id !=' => 2]);  //status = 2 means the device is out of order

}
```

Now this works in my `index` view, but it work also in another two actions where I filter the records using the Search plugin.

I want this specific filter to apply just in `index` action, while all the other filters should works in the other actions of the Devices Controller

Is there another way to achieve what I'm trying to do using cakeDC plugin or I should use some custom code in my `index` action inside the controller? It would be easy but I'd like to find a more clean solution

Answer (score 0):

> I want this behavior to apply just in index action, not everytime I apply a filter

In your controller:

```
if ($this->request->action === 'index') {
    $this->loadComponent('Search.Prg');
}
```

However, I would recommend [the FoC Search plugin](https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/search). It has a better architecture and suits Cake3 better. It can do the same but has a lot less code than the CDC plugin.

Comment: I understand that my question was not clear so I edited. I don't want to disable the search plugin, but just a specific search criterion for that specific action. I'll take a look at the FoC search plugin, but I have a lot of actions using cakeDC seach plugin.

Comment: Then just unset($this->filterArgs['filterName'])?